# Graph theory for Networks

Tags: electrical, network, graph

To use the formula, 
[Bf][Zb][Bf'][I] = [Bf][Zb][Is] - [Bf][Vs]
for the concerned, or any tree, should [Vs] and [Is], be written with respect to the directed tree I've taken, or with respect to the current direction in the loop? I mean the signs of the elements in [Vs] and [Is]...[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way this works is you go through the diagram and label each current and voltage. Each current needs a direction. You can pick any direction for the currents that you want.

You might get bunch of equations that look like this, for the resistance sections:

\$ \frac{V_{nodex}-V_{nodey}}{R}=I\$

Notice that

\$ \frac{V_{nodex}-V_{nodey}}{R}=I\$

is the same as this (nodex and nodey are reversed below, hard to see):

\$ \frac{V_{nodey}-V_{nodex}}{R}=-I\$

So as long as you remember to keep things consistent by correctly labeling and using the same direction if the label for the equation, you'll get the right answers.